# Why bottom underline in active tabs is present in Chrome?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, profile-page

The bottom underline  is Present in **Google Chrome 64.0.3282.119**.

> Please check the below screen shot for  underline is present in in Google Chrome 64.0.3282.119. linux

[image]

Please check the below screen shot for  underline is not present in Mozilla Firefox 58.0.

[image]

Comment: I’d say the line being present on Chrome is the bug, and the design works properly on FF

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for the information  i have updated my question

Comment: No repro in Chrome 67 / Win 10

Comment: I've tagged this as 'norepro' because the bug is not present at standard zoom settings, which is what is supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your browser has a non-standard zoom setting.

At default zoom there isn't a border on the active tab.

Demo when zoomed in/out:

[image]